# SQL Case When Statement for Id with multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have a table like so

```
Id   Code
1    03J0
1    0304
1    03HI
2    033I
2    03J5
3    03J4
4    030H
```

I want to do a case when statement, when there is any occurrence where the Id has a Code that is like '%03J' then Happy otherwise Sad. How do I do this when an Id has multiple rows of different codes?

Intended output

```
Id Emotion
1  Happy
2  Happy
3  Happy
4  Sad
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when code like '03J%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'Happy' else 'Sad' end) as emotion
from t
group by id;
```

Using the ordering of strings, you can simplify this to:

```
select id,
       min(case when code like '03J%' then 'Happy' else 'Sad' end) as emotion
from t
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f6885579a1c3f1d86df022e5cc2d8159) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Logic for this seems correct, However, I'm getting "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected, near 'then'." error.

Comment: I think you have to call the column name "case when code like '%03J'

Comment: @Eisen . . . I fixed the code and added a fiddle.  The logic in your question is not correct either.  The pattern you want is `''03J%'` not `'%03J'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `self-join`. Judging from your sampple data, I think you want `'03J%'` instead of `'%03J'`

```
select distinct a.id, case when b.code is not null then 'Happy' else 'Sad' end as emotion
from mytable a
left join mytable b on a.id=b.id and b.code like '03J%';
```